# Wrong spam classification + stop/look/listen + temporary ban from reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

Please note that I am not complaining, but rather, that I am reporting (if anyone cares) an incident that I consider to be a malfunction rather than a sound decision from the system.

While reviewing first posts, I was given [this test](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19843214), accompanied by the warning "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully".

I followed the link provided by the user, which pointed to a high quality answer by the same person.

While I agree that this person should have flagged the question as a duplicate instead, his response wasn't spam at all. So, I thought that I would upvote the answer to help said user and maybe the training of the algorithm that recognizes spam, ***and then flag the answer as a duplicate***. This way, it would be removed and nobody would be harmed.

Instead, I got "look and listen" and then got banned for two days from reviewing.

I think this is unfair to both the other user and me, and that the spam detection algorithm should at least look if the link contained within an answer of questionable quality points to some Stack Exchange network post before deciding it is spam.

I think that many people would have made the same decision.

As a side note, I think that my reviews are most often more useful that not. I  imagine that the ratio of flags/declined flags is a good indicator of that. On `370` flags, only `2.16` percent (8 flags) have been declined.

Comment: The warning says that it is _possible_ spam. I agree that it isn't spam, but it is a link-only answer. Therefore it is still not-an-answer (NAA). You shouldn't upvote such answers.

Comment: And, as usual: if you are banned, it's not just for this audit. So I honestly suggest you take those 2 days to take a break from review and come back refreshed, alert, and carefully reviewing

Comment: @Patrice Well yes, but the problem is that the audit system has very strange behavior, as it has been already pointed out on meta numerous times, you can get "stop/look/listen" even for raising a flag that was slightly different that what it expects, and that is the sort of audit failure that I get from time to time. I'm not really complaining though, I'm just saying that the system lacks flexibility and that some ambiguous questions like that should be removed from audits.

Comment: @Ash,  the review queues audits are brutal, posting on metadata will almost never solve the issue unless it was a really really bad review queue.  Your best bet is to skip questions you feel weird about.

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks for your comment. You are right, I will try to skip most from now on. I didn't really mean to complain about my case, but just report something that looks like a malfunction to me. I will edit the question to clarify that. I like to think that the ones who designed the classification/spam detection/audit system care about those feedbacks.

Comment: "Sorry I'm late to the party!" with link to another answer should never be upvoted as-is... At very least you could have edited the post to remove fluff and add summary. Could have posted as answer but I'm late to the party :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well... This is an exceptional situation, where the answer is at risk of being classified as spam when it isn't. In that case I still think that upvote+flag to close as low qualiy (or upvote+edit) is a logical decision. If I had upvoted and moved on, yes, I would have been at fault. But here, I couldn't just downvote and let it be detected as spam...

Comment: I’m going to be direct: please stop upvoting such crap. There is nothing to save in this answer. This is just a link, not an answer. Not only did it not deserve an upvote but it should be downvoted, voted to close and voted to delete. Spam or not spam is irrelevant here: your upvote was way off base.

Comment: @Moritz I strongly disagree with you. A poorly worded answer that points to a high quality link should be edited, and is not "crap". It is just poorly worded. You just mark the question as a duplicate of the first one, you still help people and nobody gets hurt. If your primary concern is helping the OP, then you can tolerate a poorly worded answer to exist for two hours before it is edited or the original question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Moritz I am not advocating that we keep those answers. Yes they are of poor quality. But the remedy is quite simple, and doesn't need to be as harsh as deletion: you can just edit it, or mark as duplicate. As I have said numerous times, the "upvote" was just a pseudo-hack to help train the spam filter and edit/flag the question afterwards. I never intended to endorse that answer as is. If what I do has no effect on the spam filter, then why not  display a warning about it, or add a link to the "potential spam" warning that displays info about its workings?

Comment: `I am not advocating that we keep those answers` Yes you are, by upvoting them. That’s what you don’t understand. Oh and also what you’re doing does not train the spam filter. Please just stop. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Moritz ` Please just stop. Thanks. :) ` That type of condescending comment is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ash Sorry about "Please just stop", I didn't know it could be perceived as rude in this context. In my native language this is an innocuous colloquialism. That being said, you are definitely doing things backwards, Ash. You think you are helping, but not only you're not helping but you're destroying/stopping the work we're doing. You're wasting your time, and ours. That makes me sad. I hope you can see that at some point and change your habits on this topic. Thanks.

Comment: @Moritz No worries. I don't intend to keep upvoting crap. As you can see all of this has happened because I am completely clueless about how the spam filter is trained.

Answer (score 6):

The warning about spam is not intended to make you think it's a binary decision, is this spam or not. It's intended to make you look at it more carefully and use your best judgement and full attention to see exactly what is or isn't wrong with it.

You said, [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368665/wrong-spam-classification-stop-look-listen-temporary-ban-from-reviews#comment595124_368665):

> Well... This is an exceptional situation, where the answer is at risk of being classified as spam when it isn't. In that case I still think that upvote+flag to close as low qualiy (or upvote+edit) is a logical decision. If I had upvoted and moved on, yes, I would have been at fault. But here, I couldn't just downvote and let it be detected as spam...

A post that has that warning above it is not, as far as I know, going to have anything spam-related done with it unless it is flagged as spam. So if you flag it as something else, or downvote, or cast delete votes, or whatever else, the system will not get confused by those actions. So the "exceptional situation" does not play out the way you had thought.

A post with a possible-spam warning is almost never worth upvoting, and frequently not worth commenting on or editing, either. This is especially true as the warning is particularly common on audits.

In the particular case of link-only self-promotional answers that link to other SO answers, there's no reason to upvote, and several different ways to flag that would be more or less correct. Anyone who posts an answer that links to one of their other answers could, at the very least, give context, a disclaimer for their own involvement, and a customized explanation. If they couldn't be bothered to do all of those, they shouldn't post it in the first place, and the answer should be flagged as NAA, or ♦-flagged as self-promotional if the disclaimer is left out. Anyone with at least 15 rep that is answering basically the same thing to a question that is basically similar should not answer, but flag as a duplicate, and such answers can and probably should be downvoted to get them to take a hint and do the right thing already. (These answers may or may not also qualify to be flagged as NAA, or as self-promotion.)

Finally, any time you see something counter-intuitive or baffling, like a "possible spam" warning on a post that at some point or other gets to something quite nice, you should click the small "link" link in the right column of the review interface to see the post you're reviewing in full context, which will often give you a good hint as to whether it's an audit, or whether there are some other non-obvious aspects to the situation that your review should take into account. Or, of course, you can just skip. [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: From what I remember, when you go to the link from an audit to see the full context and come back, it says something like "this review isn't available anymore". But if you are correct yes, I'll do that from now on. However, as much as I agree with all you say, I think that you are missing my point. I don't say that such posts are upvote-worthy. I'm saying that the way the audit is presented, e.g. with "potential spam" at the top, can induce the sort of "hacky" behavior I exhibited, because the person who is being reviewed will also feel responsible for training the spam filter.

Comment: @Ash ctrl+click, open in new tab ... (which is what I always do for those Spam warning reviews as I see it as an invitation to verify if the system was right in their assessment) ... also when reviewing answers, the question and other answers matter.